# How to get rid of ENTIRE frame in Chrome packaged app

Tags: google-chrome-app

In my Chrome Packaged App I am using:

```
chrome.app.window.create('window.html',{'bounds':{'width':99,'height':99},frame:'none'});
```

in an attempt to get a frameless rectangle that I can draw in.  Unfortunately, it misses the mark by a few pixels (which is not acceptable for my application).  While the frame is small, it is still there - it has slightly rounded corners visible as a black pixel in each corner.

How can I get rid of the rounded corners and claim control over the complete rectangular area?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows? If so, then it might be a symptom of [Chromium bug #323985](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=323985). Your example works fine for me on Linux with Xorg and KWin.

Comment: Yes. That is the bug I reported.